# Chocolatey - How to install hidden and unlisted package?

Tags: chocolatey

I'd like to install the package available at chocolatey, but listed as hidden\unlisted:

> This package is unlisted and hidden from package listings.

Example of such package:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/napiprojekt

Chocolatey command line `cinst napiprojekt` yields an error:

> Failures
>    - napiprojekt - napiprojekt not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.  If you specified a particular version and
>   are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name
>   exists but the version does not.  Version: ""  Source(s):
>   "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"

How can I force Chocolatey to install hidden and unlisted package?

Comment: Based on the error, you have not provided Chocolatey, a valid source for the package.

Comment: @Ramhound: I want to install it from the official Chocolatey repo.

Comment: It does not appear to be in that repoistory based on the error that is being generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install an unlisted package, you need to know the version you are attempting to install and pass `--version ###` with `choco install pkgname`.

However if you read the comments, this package was unlisted because of the VirusTotal scan results - https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d1baa923cf2a8ed8c93393b74df3a29907da85ccb2eb82795d431f6493f87fca/analysis/1454729257/

It's probably better to understand why something is unlisted first before attempting to install it. Normally packages that are safe or known to be good are not going to be unlisted.

Comment: Another example: maintainers set package as unlisted, when downloads URL stopped working.

Comment: That is an anti-pattern - with pro licensees the package may still work for them due to the CDN.